# Cloudify Composer - Resizing/Rearrange nodes or components boxes' size

Tags: cloudify, tosca

### Question

Is it possible to change nodes highness and width in Cloudify Composer ?

### Context

I am currently trying to describe a (future) application, in TOSCA, using Cloudify.
This model is used in a designing process, therefore I have different environments (dev, qual, prod …) which have nested into them physical clusters of machines, which hosts different software components and so on.
The problem is the display in the Cloudify – Composer, as of now I am not able to change the nodes layout and therefore nested components are side to side. Due to hugh amount of components is it not easily readable.
I have tried to tweak the info.yaml in the Resources tab, but it does not seem to bring change.

Hence my need to custom those boxes and the components layout (Windows Visio’s style).

### Ad-hoc

If there is no solution currently implemented, how is it possible to check if such feature is going to develop (or not) ?

Many thanks,
L.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Composer does have an `info.yaml` file, that you can edit in the "Resources" tab, and change the `width` and `height` parameters there.

However, actually doing that, did nothing when I tried it :/

The Composer is a closed-source component, and hasn't seen a ton of development in the recent months, so it's possible that this feature won't be added. However, I'll let the UI team know of this, thanks!